# mobile devices dont see radio button onchange

Tags: events, radio-button, timeout

I have 2 buttons on a pop up ad and depending on what they select do totally different things. However they dont seem to work on mobile. I cant figure out and alternative. Also I would like a delay of like 2 sec before the action but im not sure how to use timeout in this situation. I tired to use onkeyup but that did not work nor does onclick.

```
<div class="modal-content">
<span class="close">&times;</span>                       
<div class="radcen">  
<input type="radio" id="yes" value="Yes" onchange="window.location.href = 'https://www.example.com/';"><label class="free-label four col" for="yes">Yes</label>
<input type="radio"id="no" value="No" onchange="myModal.style.display = 'none'"><label class="basic-label four col" for="no">No</label>
</div>
</div><!-- Modal content -->
```

and the script

```
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");


// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When page loads display pop up
window.onload = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}



// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div class="radcen">  
<input type="radio" name="maincov" id="yes" value="Yes"><label class="free-label four col" for="yes">Yes</label>
<input type="radio" name="maincov" id="no" value="No"><label class="basic-label four col" for="no">No</label>
</div>
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
mod content
</div>
<script>
//radio  timeout
let timeout;
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
document.getElementById("yes").addEventListener("change", yestime);
document.getElementById("no").addEventListener("change", notime);
function notime(){timeout = setTimeout(no, 300);}
function yestime(){timeout = setTimeout(yes, 300);}
function no(){modal.style.display = "none";}
function yes(){window.location.href = 'https://www.example.com/';}
</script>   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Given that you’ve posted an answer, it seems you’ve solved your own problem and no longer need help. Is that correct? If so, you should [edit] this answer to include an explanation of what you’re doing and why you believe this solves your problem. As is, it’s really unclear, and unlikely to help future members of the community who have a similar problem.

Comment: java script is weird inline it dont like change and radios dont register onchange in mobile so an event listener does so document.getElementById("elementID").addEventListener("change", run this function after delay); allows me to add the timeout function and pass the values onto that.